# Acceleration of a static observer in Schwarzschild measured in locally inertial frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, acceleration

Consider a static observer at $r=R>2M$ with four velocity given by
$$U^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}=(1-\frac{2M}{R})^{-1/2}\delta^\mu_0$$
in the Schwarzschild metric
$$ds^2=-(1-\frac{2M}{r})dt^2+(1-\frac{2M}{r})^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2.$$

**Question:** What is the special relativistic acceleration [as per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_mechanics#Force)
$$a^\hat{i}=\frac{d}{d\hat{t}}\frac{d}{d\tau}x^\hat{i}\,$$
of the static observer in locally inertial coordinates (hatted) which are momentarily at rest with respect the the static observer?

Presumably one could express the $a^\hat{i}$ in terms of $R$ and $M$ only using $U^\mu$ and the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation, even without explicitly finding Riemann normal coordinates, but I don't yet see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a static observer you typically would construct Fermi normal coordinates, not Riemann normal coordinates. The latter would only be valid around a single event on the observer's worldline, that at which we consider the local inertial frame momentarily comoving with the observer. Fermi normal coordinates on the other hand are valid all along the observer's worldline given a tetrad Fermi-Walker transported along the worldline.

That being said, for what you wish to calculate there is no need to construct a Fermi normal coordinate system. This would only be required if we wanted to explicitly compute quantities that involved, say, the connection coefficients associated with the tetrad, or if we wanted to compute quantities evaluated some small distance away from the central worldline.

We have simply $$ a^{\hat{\mu}}e_{\hat{\mu}} = a^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$$ where $e_{\hat{\mu}}$ is the local inertial frame of the static observer and $\partial_{\mu}$ is a coordinate basis. All we have to do now is match the two sides.

The RHS is easy to calculate and is simply $$ a^{\mu} = \frac{M}{r^2}\delta^{\mu}_r$$ 
and since $$e_{\hat{r}} = (1 - \frac{2M}{r})^{1/2}\partial_r $$ 
we find $$a^{\hat{r}} = (1 - \frac{2M}{r})^{-1/2}a^r = (1 - \frac{2M}{r})^{-1/2}\frac{M}{r^2}
$$ 
Note this blows up as we approach the event horizon, as we would expect.

Comment: That's just the norm of the four-acceleration for a stationary observer. Is the calculation as simple as that?

Comment: @JohnRennie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_fields_in_general_relativity#Example:_Static_observers_in_Schwarzschild_vacuum

Comment: @FenderLesPaul "...where $e_\hat{\mu}$ the local inertial frame of the static observer" isn't a static observer accelerated wrt an inertial, i.e. freely falling one? Why would the components of acceleration be the same in the frame of a static observer as in the basis corresponding to locally inertial coordinates?

Comment: @Jawwar The tetrad $e_{\hat{\mu}}$ is defined to be, at any given event on the static observer's worldline, the local inertial frame momentarily comoving with the static observer at that event. The $a^{\hat{i}}$ in the OP is measured with respect to this frame.

Comment: @Jawwar Note everything I said above is assuming the acceleration is evaluated on the worldline of the observer i.e. the freely falling observer is coincident with the static observer at some event. Are you asking for the acceleration when the freely falling observer is some distance away from the observer (but still not too far away that Fermi-normal coordinates are invalid)?

Comment: @FenderLesPaul I do mean the acceleration as measured by a freely falling observer coincident at some event. Its not clear to me how you found the r component of the tetrad for the local inertial frame. The article you link to shows that the static observer's acceleration is non zero, and therefore doesn't qualify as an inertial frame.